# What is the number of locations that can be added for proxymity alert in android

Tags: android, geolocation, location, locationmanager, proximity

What is the limit of number of locations that can be added for proxymity alert in android? 
Can I add 100,000 of locations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the implementation of the `ProximityListener` in Android, which doesn't seem to have a hard limit for adding locations:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java#L1499

However, adding 100,000 locations to the proximity listener at once seems like a very bad idea.

You'll definitely hit the Android memory limit of an application at some point.

You can get the approximate per-application memory class of the current device via `ActivityManager.getMemoryClass()`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass()

Instead of adding 100,000 locations at once to the proximityListener, I'd suggest adding a subset based on the known geographic area of the device.  This would require a spatial database to assist in both a persistent location store as well as spatial queries for returning nearby locations.